# I'm trying to get :after:hover to work

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, background-image, opacity

I have a background image that I'm trying to emulate opacity on. `opacity:.5;` doesn't work, so I decided to add a semi-transparent white square over the top.

```
.pic:after{
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.pic:after:hover{
    content:"";
    background-color: rgba(118, 255, 161, 0.35);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In addition to the selector inversion, you could put the image in the after element and set opacity as you like on it :) See http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/

Comment: I'm really glad you posted that!! I already know that technique will help me in other areas in the future! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.pic:after` is not an element in the DOM. You have to apply the `:hover` on `.pic` and then select its :pseudo-element(`.pic:hover:after`).

```
.pic:hover:after{
    content:"";
    background-color: rgba(118, 255, 161, 0.35);
}
```